# CCLabelTTF SetString not Updating

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, cclabelttf

I'm using a `CCLabelTTF` to show the score of the player on the screen. However, when I'm calling `setString` to update the score label, it doesn't update (so it always stays at 0).

Here's my code :

In **Player.m**, I initiate a new PlayerHUD object:

```
- (id) init{
    if (self = [super init]){
        playerHUD = [[PlayerHUD alloc] loadPlayerInterface];
        [self addChild:playerHUD z:UPLAYER_Z];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In **PlayerHUD.m**, I initiate the Score Label :

```
- (id) loadPlayerInterface{
    if (self = [super init]){
        score = 0;
        //Score Label
        lblScore = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score] fontName:@"pixel" fontSize:24];
        [self addChild:lblScore z:1000];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Still in **PlayerHUD.m**, here's my update function :

```
- (void) updateScore:(NSInteger)_newscore{
    score = _newscore;
    [lblScore setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score]];
}
```

And, in **Player.m**, I call the update function here :

```
- (void) addScore{
    int scoreToAdd = 50

    score += scoreToAdd;

    NSLog(@"Score:%d", score);
    [playerHUD updateScore:score];
}
```

Comment: what's your log for `NSLog(@"Score:%d", score);` ?

Comment: Are you using ARC and your label property is weak ?

Comment: put breakpoints into addScore and updateScore: methods and check if they are called

Comment: @Morion Weird enough, my updateScore: method never get called (I tried with a breakpoint like you said!) Do you have an idea?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore My log is alright, it's updating well (Score:50, Score:100, etc) And if by ARC you mean property and synthesize, no, I'm not using that, should I? (I don't really know what means ARC)

Comment: @UnluckyPotato if your breakpoint is not coming the put some log there. And if that log doesn't prints then `playerHUD` is probably `nil`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I've tried and nothing prints, so what should I do to make it non-nil?

Comment: @UnluckyPotato some where in your code `playerHUD` is becoming nil. Please check that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've find what was wrong, and I thought I would post it here, if anyone ever encounter this:

The problem was that, for a reason that I still ignore, I needed to set a `@property` and `@synthesize` for my `playerHUD` object because, after some operations, it was becoming nil, like @InderKumarRathore said. So setting a property and synthesize for it solved the problem and never get lost again!

And after some research, I think that's because of some modifications between cocos2D **v.0.98** (the one I used before) and cocos2D **v1.0** (the one I use right now) about memory management!

Anyway, thank you all for your support, much appreciated!

Comment: It's great that you have solved your problem. Please accept your answer so that your question is closed.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this issue using the code below (set string to an empty string then reSet it to your string)

```
[label setString:@""];
[label setString:yourString];
```